# I want to sort the objects in another array order

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

①There is an array like this.

```js
const array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'E'];
```

②There is an object.

```js
const obj = {
  'b': ['aa', 'bb', 'cc'],
  'a': ['ac', 'bc', 'cs'],
  'c': ['as', 'b', 'c_1'],
  'E': ['a_4', 'b_4', 'c_4'],
  'd': ['a_4', 'b_4', 'c_4']
};
```

When you want to rearrange these according to the arrangement order of ①.

I want the result to be like this.

```js
const obj = {
  'a': ['ac', 'bc', 'cs'],
  'b': ['aa', 'bb', 'cc'],
  'c': ['as', 'b', 'c_1'],
  'd': ['a_4', 'b_4', 'c_4'],
  'E': ['a_4', 'b_4', 'c_4']
};
```

Is it possible to do it only with the map function and sort?

Comment: why do you want to order your object? the order of keys are not guaranteed

Comment: The order is not guaranteed. Is there any good way?

Comment: good way for what? do you need to display this as a list or something?

Answer (score 1):

Using [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'E'];

const obj = {
  'b': ['aa', 'bb', 'cc'],
  'a': ['ac', 'bc', 'cs'],
  'c': ['as', 'b', 'c_1'],
  'E': ['a_4', 'b_4', 'c_4'],
  'd': ['a_4', 'b_4', 'c_4']
};

// console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))

const res = Object.keys(obj)
    .sort((a, b) => array.indexOf(a) - array.indexOf(b))
    .reduce((a, k) => ({...a, [k]: obj[k] }), {})

console.log(JSON.stringify(res))
```

Using [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) and [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

```js
const array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'E'];

const obj = {
  'b': ['aa', 'bb', 'cc'],
  'a': ['ac', 'bc', 'cs'],
  'c': ['as', 'b', 'c_1'],
  'E': ['a_4', 'b_4', 'c_4'],
  'd': ['a_4', 'b_4', 'c_4']
};

// console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))

const res = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj)
    .sort((a, b) => array.indexOf(a[0]) - array.indexOf(b[0])))

console.log(JSON.stringify(res))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we don't need sort because, our goal is to arrange the **obj** in terms of **array**.

```js
const array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'E'];
const obj = {
  'b': ['aa', 'bb', 'cc'],
  'a': ['ac', 'bc', 'cs'],
  'c': ['as', 'b', 'c_1'],
  'E': ['a_4', 'b_4', 'c_4'],
  'd': ['a_4', 'b_4', 'c_4']
};

let result = array.reduce((accumulator, currentItem)=>{
    accumulator[currentItem] = obj[currentItem];
    return accumulator;
},{});

console.log(result)
```